# Synchronized warp vote returns diverging result?

Tags: cuda

A`__ballot_sync()` function that appears to be convergent instead returns a diverging result, reproduced with the following code:

```
__global__ void testKernel(uint32_t* testBuffer)
{
    if (!threadIdx.x)
        atomicAdd(&testBuffer[0], 1);

    printf("%u: %u \n", threadIdx.x, __ballot_sync(__activemask(), 1));
}

int main()
{
    uint32_t* tBuffer;
    cudaMalloc(&tBuffer, 1024 * sizeof(uint32_t));
    
    testKernel<<<1,32>>>(tBuffer);

    cudaFree(tBuffer);
    return 0;
}
```

Which results in the following print output:

```
 1     : 4294967294
 . . .
 31    : 4294967294
 0     : 1
```

My understanding of the SIMT programming model is that:

1. Threads within a warp execute in logical but not physical lockstep.
2. When threads within the same warp diverge, threads within one branch will execute, while opposing branches are masked.

Based on these two conditions, what I expect to happen in this code block is that `threads 1-31` hang while `thread 0` performs the atomic addition, and afterwards the threads reconverge. Instead it appears that `threads 1-31` participate in their own ballot, and later `thread 0` participates in its own ballot.

**Why do the threads fail to reconverge after the atomic addition?**

Some notes that may be of interest:

- Divergence presents only with atomics. Performing non-atomic addition, even looping 10000 times, does not cause divergence.
- Threads can be forced to reconverge by adding a `__syncthreads` after the atomic.
- Divergence does not present if generate debug information `-G` is disabled.

Debugging info:

-gencode=arch=compute_75,code="sm_75,compute_75"
--use-local-env -ccbin "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30133\bin\HostX86\x64" -x cu   -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\include" -I"C:\Users\x\Desktop\VCPCKG\vcpkg\installed\x64-windows\include" -I"C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v12.0\include"  -G   --keep-dir x64\Debug  -maxrregcount=0  --machine 64 --compile -cudart static  -g  -DWIN32 -DWIN64 -D_DEBUG -D_CONSOLE -D_MBCS -Xcompiler "/EHsc /W3 /nologo /Od /FS /Zi /RTC1 /MDd " -Xcompiler "/Fdx64\Debug\vc142.pdb" -o C:\Users\x\source\repos\WarpDivergence\x64\Debug\kernel.cu.obj "C:\Users\x\source\repos\WarpDivergence\kernel.cu"

Running on a 2080 super.

Comment: What happens when you disable independent thread scheduling?

Comment: Answer suggested by another commenter answered my question perfectly! Thank you!